# Deleting spaces in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code sample that I use on a table to delete spaces in cells. I want to ask if someone has a better and quicker way to the `Trim` function on a table than what I have:

This is the sample:

```
If Sheets("Main").Cells(8, 6) = 1 Then
    strName = Sheets("Main").Cells(8, 3)
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="V:\á÷øåú ùëø\ãåçåú\ãåçåú çæåúééí\ãåçåú ìäîøä\exhr0101.csv"
    Columns(7).Delete
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Trim all cells.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'ñâéøú çæåúé î÷åø
    Windows("exhr0101.csv").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'áéöåò Trim
    Windows("Trim all cells.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Data").Select
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    cell = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)
    Next cell
    'äãá÷ä áâéìéåï äãá÷ä
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Target").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Here is my specific trim:

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
cell = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)
Next cell
```

Comment: For a start is there a typed function Trim$ ?

Comment: `Application.Worksheetfunction.Trim()` will leave a single space between words in a cell.  **Is this what you want??**

Comment: @QHarr what do you mean

Comment: @Gary'sStudent yes. I know what trim does. I want it to do it  quicker

Comment: Can you replace Trim with Trim$ without raising an error or it being swopped back to Trim. I can’t remember.

Comment: @QHarr i will check

Comment: Sorry on mobile but in cases where a typed function exists it should be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid loop altogether.

```
 With Activesheet.UsedRange
     .Value = Application.Trim(.Value)
 End With
```

**Warning:** will give error if any cell has more than 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the data in a specific worksheet to use Trim, or any macro for that matter. It looks like you are copying data from your worksheet to "Trim all cells.xlsm." In reality, if you just have the workbook open and make sure the active cell is on the workbook you want to trim, you should be good.

Also, setting Application.ScreenUpdating to false before you run the code will speed it up dramatically. Just make sure you set it back to true at the end of the code.